# Can't launch JD-GUI on Ubuntu 12.10 64bits

Tags: 12.10, package-management, software-installation, gtk, libraries

When I try to open JD-GUI via the terminal it gives me the following error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I tried to install the library using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

And the output is the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcanberra-gtk-module
```

So I went out to download the [file]https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libgtk2.0-0-dbg that seems to have a .deb installer of the library and when I click to install it the Ubuntu Software Center opens and it displays the following error:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libgtk2.0-0(=2.24.10-2)
```

Note: After trying all of this I did a `apt-get upgrade` and a `apt-get update` and tried it all over again but it still didn't work. I've been trying this for hours, I already googled but I found no solution.

Comment: I faced same problem. It helps for me just `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386`. I have 64-bit ubuntu  installed

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you should install "libgtk2.0-0" (meaning the 64bit version) instead of "libgtk2.0-0:i386" (32bit version).
I noticed from the title that you are using a 64bit ubuntu version.